# Android: Gridview not showing correctly

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a screen with a single column grid that is 180px wide and attaches to the right side of the screen. The problem I'm facing is that the background of the gridview paints the whole screen and not just that 180px I specified in the XML (thus blocking my background pic specified in the LinearLayout).

Neither using weight nor gravity solves the problem.

Seems simple enough yet I've been toying with this for hours to no avail. Thanks in advance for your help.

My layout.xml as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/main_bkgd">
<GridView 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:numColumns="1" 
    android:columnWidth="180px" 
    android:verticalSpacing="6dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/mainmenu_grid" 
    android:gravity="right" 
    android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:layout_weight=".35">
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `android:stretchMode` attribute to be `none`:

```
android:stretchMode="none"
```

in your `GridView` declaration.

Setting the GridView's width to "`190px`" would also solve this problem (with the defaultSelector's margins being of 5 pixels wide for the `GridView`, you need an extra 10px).

Other: you should probably use a `ListView` if you have only one column anyway...

Comment: Thank you. Fixing width to 190 does the trick. Don't even need to use Stretch Mode...

Comment: using the strechmode would be cleaner, however

Answer (score 0):

Change background color of Gridview
        android:background="#333"
I do not know why is this happening with default it is totally white font and back therefor it is not visible to. I think it is bug in earlier versions.